# how count result php from if

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm making a difference today in the database and the result goes ,

```
<?php 
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
   $u = $row->jadwalkal; *//from database*
   $tgl1 = $u;
   $tgl2 = date("Y-m-d");
   $selisih = strtotime($tgl1) -  strtotime($tgl2);
   $hari = $selisih/(60*60*24);
   if ($hari < 0){ ?>
   <div class="label label-danger"><?php echo "Telat $hari  hari";?></div>
   <?php
    }elseif ($hari < 7) { ?>
    <div class="label label-info"><?php echo "Tinggal $hari hari";?></div>
    <?php
    }else{ ?>
    <div class="label label-success"><?php echo "Masih $hari hari";?></div>

    <?php }
    ?>
```

but I want to ask how to calculate the results of **$hari** in php by **if** ..

count total = **$hari < 7**

count total = **$hari < 0**

count total = **$hari**

Comment: Where is the $hari variable is initialized?

Comment: @raveenanigam Sorry script None the less, I have fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use variable in each if case and then print all the three variable you get result.